# How to get notification in xamarin forms on firebase data change?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

For example: get notify on background when ever there is a change in firebase database...I.e on insert,Delete record etc
Is it possible? Please let me know how can I achieve this I am new to xamarin forms.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: which nuget are you using?

Comment: @Prateek i am using **FirebaseDatabase.net** nuget package  for firebase connection.

Answer (score 2):

Try subscribe method

```cs
 var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://project_id.firebaseio.com/");
            firebase.Child("dataname").AsObservable<datatype>().Subscribe(obs =>
            {


                switch (obs.EventType)
                {
                    case Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.InsertOrUpdate:
                        break;
                    case Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.Delete:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
```

Comment: this line giving error: **firebase.Child("dataname").AsObservable<datatype>().Subscribe(obs =>** dose not exist in current context

Comment: @USAMAMALIK what is the complete error. did you replace `dataname` with database name and `datatype` with `Type` of database type?