# Notification on change of data in Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, database, firebase, xamarin, notifications

Hi so I've implemented a method based on this answer:
[How to get notification in xamarin forms on firebase data change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698719/how-to-get-notification-in-xamarin-forms-on-firebase-data-change)
But I'm having trouble getting it working.

Here's my code:

```
      void DoFirebaseObserve()
      {
            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(Constants.FirebaseProjectUrl);
            firebase.Child("RegisterUserTable").AsObservable<RegisterUser>().Subscribe(obs =>
            {
                switch (obs.EventType)
                {
                    case Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.InsertOrUpdate:
                        Console.WriteLine("InsertOrUpdate");
                        break;
                    case Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType.Delete:
                        Console.WriteLine("Delete");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });

       }
```

I call this code in the OnAppearing method of my app's home page. I've tried with and without the while (true) {} condition.

When I add, update or delete a record in firebase, nothing happens in my application. The writelines are never called.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why would you put this code in a while loop?  You only need to setup the listener once

Comment: I initially tried it without the while loop and it didn't work so I gave it a try.

Comment: you need to get rid of it, that will eventually crash your app.  Have you considered that maybe it is getting called, but with a different event type than you're checking for?

Comment: I've took the loop out of my code, thanks. The Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEventType only has two constants, InsertOrUpdate and Delete, ie i don't think it can be anything else.

Comment: if may be useful to put a `WriteLine()` outside of the switch, just in case.  Have you checked that `AsObservable` is actually returning data?

Comment: I've put a couple `WriteLine`s in and they're not printing to the console. I'm not really sure how I'd check if the `AsObservable` is returning data

Comment: assign it to a variable and check the contents with the debugger.  The point is to validate that you're attaching the `Subscribe` to a valid node

Comment: This is the object type `{System.Reactive.AutoDetachObserver<Firebase.Database.Streaming.FirebaseEvent<UberClone.Helpers.RegisterUser>>} ` but i dont see any useful information https://ibb.co/D91VV90

Comment: This is a known issue and has been reported here  ： https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/issues/260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out how to do it through using Google Cloud Functions in the Firebase console.

**Step 1. Set up FCM in your .Net code**

Follow this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos

Once you have got your FCM token from that device, you can add it to your realtime database (I did this myself in the firebase console manually for testing).

**Step 2. Set up Cloud Functions**

Follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpI3Bbhlcas&t=1104s&ab_channel=uNicoDev

**Step 3. Create a function to send the message**

You can use this node.js code in your cloud functions to send up to 500 devices:

```
// Create a list containing up to 500 registration tokens.
// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
const registrationTokens = [
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
  // …
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_N',
];

const message = {
  data: {score: '850', time: '2:45'},
  tokens: registrationTokens,
};

admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
  });
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#node.js_1

**Code Example**

Some of my code to help you get an idea of how to go about doing something like this. Can't guarantee this is the optimal method but it works.

```
    const reference = "JourneyTbl/{journeyId}";

// newJourneyAdded | listener method | Send push notif when new journey created:
exports.newJourneyAdded = functions.database.ref(reference)
    .onCreate((event, context) => {
      // where fcm tokens are stored:
      const refNotifications = "NotificationTbl";
      // get ref to RegNotTable:
      const refFcm = admin.database().ref(refNotifications);
      // array to hold all fcms from table:
      const allFcms = [];
      // get value of "NotificationTbl":
      refFcm.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        // check if there's any children:
        if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
          // loop through children:
          snapshot.forEach((element) => {
            // stringify the data:
            const asString = JSON.stringify(element);
            // parse that as a JSON object:
            const asJson = JSON.parse(asString);
            // add fcm token to array:
            allFcms.push(asJson.fcm);
          });
        }

        // if array contains something:
        if (allFcms.length > 0) {
          // construct message to send:
          const msg = {
            notification: {
              title: "Notification Title goes here",
              body: "Notification Body goes here ",
            },
            tokens: allFcms, // pass the tokens
          };
          // send that message:
          admin.messaging().sendMulticast(msg)
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.successCount + " mgs were sent sfly");
              });
        } else {
          console.log("No devices in FCM tokens list");
        }
      });
      return "ok";
    });
```